# CommandLineParser usage with multiple verb options

Tags: c#, command-line

I'm using [`CommandLineParser`](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline). When I parse my arguments based on a single verb, it works. My verb is recognized, and the command is run.

```
Parser.Default.ParseArguments<FirstOperation>(args)
    .MapResult(
        (FirstOperation operation) => RunCommand(operation)
        (IEnumerable<Error> errs) => ProcessError(errs)
    );
```

But, my program has several possible verbs the user might input. When I try to implement my parser for a second verb, `ProcessError` gets called with a `CommandLine.BadVerbSelectedError`.

```
Parser.Default.ParseArguments<FirstOperation, SecondOperation>(args)
    .MapResult(
        (FirstOperation operation) => RunCommand(operation),
        (SecondOperation operation) => RunCommand(operation),
        (IEnumerable<Error> errs) => ProcessError(errs)
    );
```

Also, the help that is written to output doesn't include either of my verbs. It seems that implementing the second verb option is somehow getting rid of all verb info for the parser. Am I implementing this incorrectly? I followed the example located [here](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline_sampleapp/blob/master/sampleapps/quickstart_verbs/Program.cs).

Note that I am giving the same input for both instances. So, I don't think my problem is with the guts of my second verb (`SecondOperation`).

Comment: Are you putting a space and a dash before each option?

Comment: My input looks something like this:

`verb --parm1 value --parm2 value`

Comment: Why the verb? Why do you have two dashes?  Shouldn't is just be :  -parm1 value -parm2 value

Comment: Two dashes because that is the syntax used in CommandLineParser. And the verb is used to direct different use cases. It's all in [the documentation](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/wiki/Verbs)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you use the following format:

```
Parser.Default.ParseArguments<FirstOperation, SecondOperation>(args)
    .WithParsed<FirstOperation>(f => f.Dojob())
    .WithParsed<SecondOperation>(s => s.Dojob()).
```

I declared my jobs as methods of the verb classes (`Dojob()`), but you can pass a delegate instead of lambda and use properties only.

Comment: Not sure if this was ever solved. I am using the suggested code format but when I pass multiple verbs I get verb not recognized back from the parser. what's the solution to this?

Comment: Make sure the verb attribute assigned to the class has a name. Use that name in the command line followed by your options. That was the issue for me. I was using the commandline like I was still processing a single verb, thereby omitting the verb name. The verb name is required when parsing for multiple verbs.

Comment: I'm sure I have the verb attribute assigned to the class has a name, but still this library can't parse multiple verbs with arguments too...